# NotSerializableException when saving an ArrayList to a text file

Tags: java, exception, serialization

I have a program that adds `PanelFurniture` objects to an `ArrayList`. When i try to save the data in a file, it is giving me the exception `java.io.NotSerializableException: PanelFurniture$1`. `PanelFurniture` is the name of the class, and it implements `Serializable` already, so I don't understand what the problem might be.

This is my code for writing the ArrayList to the file

```
if(ae.getSource() == commandButtons[5]) {
    int x = 5 , y = 11;
    File confidential = new File("secrets.txt");
    PrintWriter output = null;
    try {               
        saveFile = new FileOutputStream("myFile.dat");
        save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);                                        
        save.writeObject(orderList);
        save.close(); 

        System.out.println(orderList);              
    }
    catch (Exception e){                
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PanelFurniture` class, which is the content of your `ArrayList`, needs to implement the `Serializable` interface, as well as any anonymous inner classes (like `PanelFurniture$1`), so Java doesn't know how to read/write this data to disk.

If you don't want to use serialization, you are probably wanting to do something like this... (psuedocode)

```
Create a FileOutputStream
for (each item in the ArrayList){
  get the properties of the PanelFurniture object, and write them to the FileOutputStream.
  eg. fos.writeLine(panelFurniture.getName() + "," + panelFurniture.getValue());
  }
Close the FileOutputStream.
```

Answer (score 4):

`PanelFurniture$1` refers to an anonymous inner class, which apparently does not implement `Serializable`. So you should qualify the corresponding class member with `transient` (or make it a local variable instead), as anonymous classes are not supposed to contain serializable data. If yours does, you should turn into a normal (named) inner class and have it `implement Serializable`.

Comment: +1: you can use transient, indeed, if the member is not needed :)

Comment: ...or rethink what you are doing to see if you really want to serialize a `Panel` and it's inner classes.

Comment: well all the classes implement the Serializable

Comment: The classes do, but you have an anonymous inner class that doesn't. Do you have such a class, which might be some `Thread` code or a `Listener`. If you could paste your `PanelFurniture` code, it'd probably be easier to assist.

Comment: @Kiril, all *named* classes, you mean? As a proper anonymous inner class can't - it can only implement a single interface. If that interface were `Serializable`, you would have a useless empty class, as `Serializable` is a marker interface with no methods. It would make both your and our life easier if you showed us the source code of your class...

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the JavaDoc for the [writeObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

> Throws:
>
> NotSerializableException -  Some object to be serialized does not implement the java.io.Serializable interface.

Are you sure that the elements making up your ArrayList implement the `Serializable` Interface?

Comment: all the classes implement the Serializable

Comment: @Kiril: If all the classes implement the Serializable interface then I think that the Javadoc would say otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is linked to the subModel incluyed on your arraylist

For each model on your object, you must add "implements Serializable" and include the autogenerated "private static final long serialVersionUID "

by that way you can save and entire list without any exceptions